# Create a cumulative count of events and retain first year before and after every event

Tags: r, data-manipulation, panel-data

I have a longitudinal dataset containing individuals along with information about where they are currently residing. The code below creates an example df:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,     
         1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7,  
         2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8,  
         1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8   
         ), 
  year = c(rep(2009, 5), 
           rep(2010, 6), 
           rep(2011, 6), 
           rep(2012, 7)),
  age = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
          2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2,
          3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3),
  town = c("0", "0", "2", "0", "0",
          "1", "2", "1", "3", "0", "1",
          "3", "1", "4", "1", "2", "1",
          "4", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "5")
)
```

I'm interested in reasons for moving (e.g., whether income, attained education, family structure etc plays a role in whether you move at all, and whether it affects the area you move to), so I've coded the event, "moved", along with "flag_first_move" using the following code:

```
df3 <- df %>%
  arrange(year, id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(first_year = min(year)) %>%
  mutate(first_town = list(town[year==first_year])) %>%
  mutate(flag_move = as.numeric(year != first_year & !(town %in% unlist(first_town)) & town !="")) %>%
  mutate(flag_first_move = (flag_move==1 & as.numeric(!duplicated(flag_move)))) %>%
  mutate(moved = case_when(town !=lag(town)  ~ 1,
                           TRUE  ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(flag_cum_move = (cumsum(c(0, diff(moved)) !=0) + 1)) #This doesn't work as intended
```

"flag_first_move" gives me the first event of a move. "moved" gives me a flag for every time an individual move. Lastly, with the attempt of creating the variable "flag_cum_move", I want a cumulative count for every event (so that every time an individual moves it adds 1) - I can't figure out how to do this!

Lastly, I want to look at the year before and after every event (move) for every individual. This is the code I've tried to accomplish this task:

```
df4 <- df3 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(any(flag_first_move == 1)) %>%
  mutate(
    year_before = ifelse(
      between(year[moved == 1] - year, 1, 1), 1, 0),
    year_after = ifelse(
      between(year - year[moved == 1], 1, 1), 1, 0),
  )
```

It works fine in the cases where only one event occurs, but in the case where multiple events follow for every year it gives me a warning for the "year_after" variable, and I don't get the intended result for this neither. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you want. It's better if you could show the expected output in the question, so if I have misunderstood something please note in the comments below and I can adjust accordingly.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  id = c(
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7,
    2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8
  ),
  year = c(
    rep(2009, 5),
    rep(2010, 6),
    rep(2011, 6),
    rep(2012, 7)
  ),
  age = c(
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3
  ),
  town = c(
    "0", "0", "2", "0", "0",
    "1", "2", "1", "3", "0", "1",
    "3", "1", "4", "1", "2", "1",
    "4", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "5"
  )
)

df3 <- df %>%
  arrange(id, year) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    first_year = min(year),
    first_town = if_else(year == first_year, town, NA_character_)
  ) %>%
  fill(first_town) %>%
  mutate(
    flag_move = if_else(year != first_year & town != first_town, 1, 0),
    flag_first_move = if_else(cumsum(flag_move) == 1, 1, 0),
    moved = if_else(town != lag(town), 1, 0)
  ) %>%
  replace_na(list(moved = 0)) %>%
  mutate(flag_cum_move = cumsum(moved))

df4 <- df3 %>%
  filter(any(flag_first_move == 1)) %>%
  mutate(
    year_before = if_else(lead(moved) == 1, 1, 0),
    year_after = if_else(lag(moved) == 1, 1, 0)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

df4
#> # A tibble: 24 × 12
#>       id  year   age town  first_year first_town flag_move flag_first_move moved
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1  2009     0 0           2009 0                  0               0     0
#>  2     1  2010     1 1           2009 0                  1               1     1
#>  3     1  2012     3 4           2009 0                  1               0     1
#>  4     2  2009     0 0           2009 0                  0               0     0
#>  5     2  2010     1 2           2009 0                  1               1     1
#>  6     2  2011     2 3           2009 0                  1               0     1
#>  7     2  2012     3 2           2009 0                  1               0     1
#>  8     3  2009     0 2           2009 2                  0               0     0
#>  9     3  2010     1 1           2009 2                  1               1     1
#> 10     3  2011     2 1           2009 2                  1               0     0
#> # … with 14 more rows, and 3 more variables: flag_cum_move <dbl>,
#> #   year_before <dbl>, year_after <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = c("id", "year"))
df[, moved := ifelse(town == shift(town, type = "lag", fill = town[1]), 0, 1), keyby = id]
df[, cummoved := cumsum(moved), keyby = id]
df[, firstmove := 0][cummoved == 1 & moved == 1, firstmove := 1][]
# 
#     id year age town moved cummoved firstmove
#  1:  1 2009   0    0     0        0         0
#  2:  1 2010   1    1     1        1         1
#  3:  1 2012   3    4     1        2         0
#  4:  2 2009   0    0     0        0         0
#  5:  2 2010   1    2     1        1         1
#  6:  2 2011   2    3     1        2         0
#  7:  2 2012   3    2     1        3         0
#  8:  3 2009   0    2     0        0         0
#  9:  3 2010   1    1     1        1         1
# 10:  3 2011   2    1     0        1         0
# 11:  3 2012   3    2     1        2         0
# 12:  4 2009   0    0     0        0         0
# 13:  4 2011   2    4     1        1         1
# 14:  4 2012   3    1     1        2         0
# 15:  5 2009   0    0     0        0         0
# 16:  5 2010   1    3     1        1         1
# 17:  6 2010   0    0     0        0         0
# 18:  6 2011   1    1     1        1         1
# 19:  6 2012   2    2     1        2         0
# 20:  7 2010   1    1     0        0         0
# 21:  7 2011   2    2     1        1         1
# 22:  7 2012   3    1     1        2         0
# 23:  8 2011   2    1     0        0         0
# 24:  8 2012   3    5     1        1         1
#     id year age town moved cummoved firstmove
```